# Go Validator Translate Error Message From Map

Tags: go, validation

I am using this package https://github.com/go-playground/validator for validator in my app to validate fields sent from user. I have difficulties in using validate map and returning error message in user readable format.

controllers.go

```
import (
    "github.com/go-playground/locales/en"
    ut "github.com/go-playground/universal-translator"
    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
)

func Validator2() map[string]any {
    user := map[string]interface{}{"name": "Name", "email": "email"}
    rules := map[string]interface{}{"name": "required,min=8,max=32", "email": "omitempty,required,email"}

    errs := validate.ValidateMap(user, rules)

    if len(errs) > 0 {
        en := en.New()
        uni = ut.New(en, en)
        trans, _ := uni.GetTranslator("en")

        log.Println(errs)

        return errs
        // The user is invalid
    }

    return map[string]any{"success": true}

    // The user is valid
}
```

It seems that the package is only able to translate using ValidationErrors, but the ValidateMap function is returning map[string]interface{}, how can I return the error messages in user readable format? I could not find any example on this anywhere in Google or SO. I have no problem using Struct, but sometimes I need validator for map. Thank you in advance.